# SQL Create view with a row whose column value depends on if another row exist in a separate table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

How can I create a view where the view is simply

| name | exist_check |
| --- | --- |
| foo | false |

The `exist_check` column is dependent on if a select query in another table returns anything or not.

For example

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo_table 
WHERE name = 'foo'
```

If that returns anything, `exist_check` in the view should be true. If it returns nothing, `exist_check` should be false.

Comment: SELECT * FROM foo_table where name = 'foo' and exist_check = true (exist_check is of type boolean) or SELECT * FROM foo_table where name = 'foo' and exist_check = 'true' (exist_check is of type char or text)

Comment: @Edouard Sorry, for clarity, the exist_check field doesn't exist in the table. I want to create it in the view based on if the select statement for foo returns anything or not.

Comment: OK sorry, my mistake. try this : `SELECT 'foo' AS name, EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM foo_table WHERE name = 'foo') AS exist_check`

Comment: Thanks! This works exactly as wanted.